# How to pass object through two viewmodels? Wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, object, mvvm, viewmodel

I hava a main view, where you have one object and you can change the properties of that object. But then I have a popup window when you click on a button: the advanced properties. But these changes that you do in the pop up window also have to be done in the object of the main view.

So I implemented a viewmodel as well for the popup. I can put here some code but this is quite useless, because I don't have anything, just 2 viewmodels with bindings with some textboxes to change the properties of that object. So the 2 viewmodels don't work together on the same object (this is what i should do i think).

It is just difficult for the popup to get to the object which you are working on in the mainview. In some way i should must be able to pass the changes which you made in the popup , to the main view (to the same object). Someone who knows how to do this? I am searching for this a long time, but i really don't know to fix or to go around my problem :( ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this, depending on your architecture. For example, if you are using a rich domain model, you may be binding directly to a Model property exposed on your view model. In which case, when you invoke the advanced property window, you can pass an instance of your existing model to that view model. Changes in the advanced property window will be bound to the same instance of your business object opened in the original window.

Alternatively, if you are using an anemic domain model where you don't expose the model directly to the view, you can still pass the same instance of the model to the new window, but use a mediator pattern (or any other standard inter-view model communication techniques) to notify the original window when the advanced window closes. In this case, the advanced window would be the publisher, and the original window the subscriber.

When notified, the original window can invalidate all of its view model bindings so that the UI is updated as appropriate.

Comment: I'm using the first i think, but yes i can give give this to the view of the advanced window. But my problem is now, what do i have to do when i close this popup, and go back to the mainscreen? Then i have to give the newly changed object back to the main viewmodel? or am i wrong now?

Comment: As mentioned, your second view model would be updating the same instance of your model, therefore you wouldn't need to update your original copy in your original view. If you just need to be notified when the advanced window closes, then as I say, you can use either standard .NET events to be notified (subscribe in the original window, publish in the advanced window), or an event aggregator, depending on what MVVM framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one ViewModel that includes all of the necessary properties (basic properties + the ones you are editing in the detailed view). Then you can just pass the same ViewModel to the popup view => thus the ViewModel object instance is the same, but two views are just a bit different and allow for editing different properties.

Comment: I think i get, so i just make one extra viewmodel? Then i pass this to popup in the constructor of this view? But when i close this popup, I have to edit the basic properties again.. How do i do this then? To pass the viewmodel again to the first viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

Where does this "domain" or "business" object, which your viewmodels operate on, come from? Find a way to share this "source" between the viewmodels.

For instance, if you are using some kind of ORM you could implement a (static) domain service, which your viewmodels ask for the object.

Example: Your DomainService could expose a method "GetPersonById(int id)" and it would return the same object to both ViewModels.

Comment: No I am implementing something that you fill up the properties in an object, and then the application writes this object away in an XML-file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have one BusinessObject which is passed to both ViewModels and each will expose what is required for that View. That way you one business object is shared accross 2 VMs